# iPhone Get UIImagePickerController Lat/Lng

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo and then upload the photo to a `WCF Service`. Along with the image, I also need to send to the latitude and longitude of the photo.

How can I get hold of this information from the photo taken?

I've searched online but can't seem to find a good source of info. I've seen about the `EXIF` data that is passed through the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` key as part of the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method. However, when I print out the contents to the log, there's no location information.

Am I missing something, do I need to turn on location services prior to taking the photo? Or is there another way to get the information?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been figuring this out for a couple of days, and finally got a solution. As already suggested, you can use **ALAssetsLibrary**.

The image picker will give you a dictionary, which contains an url that points to the asset.

The **ALAssetsLibrary**'s `assetForURL: resultBlock: failureBlock:` method uses blocks. You can read more about them from example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).
So this is how we handle the info given by the picker:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
            didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
        // We'll store the info to use in another function later
        self.imageInfo = info;

        // Get the asset url
        NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

        // We need to use blocks. This block will handle the ALAsset that's returned: 
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            // Get the location property from the asset  
            CLLocation *location = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            // I found that the easiest way is to send the location to another method
            [self handleImageLocation:location];
        };
        // This block will handle errors:
        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
            // Do something to handle the error
        };


        // Use the url to get the asset from ALAssetsLibrary,
        // the blocks that we just created will handle results
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:url 
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];

    }
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

And next the method that handles the image and location data:

```
- handleImageLocation:(CLLocation *)location 
{
    UIImage *image = [self.imageInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // Do something with the image and location data...
}
```

And of course you can also get other information about the image with this method by using keys:

```
ALAssetPropertyType
ALAssetPropertyLocation
ALAssetPropertyDuration
ALAssetPropertyOrientation
ALAssetPropertyDate
ALAssetPropertyRepresentations
ALAssetPropertyURLs
```

Comment: This is wonderful if the source type is the library, but what if it's the camera (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)? In that case, url will be nil. :(

Comment: I get the erorr: `Argument type 'void' is incomplete` when using the above code. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shredder2794 unfortunately I'm not currently using this code in any of my projects, so can't give you a good answer. Are you able to debug, which row exactly gives you this error?

Comment: The question about UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera is pretty old, but I'll answer anyway. In case you get the image directly from camera, you can get also the location yourself with [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125). You should then save the image to the photo library with the location in metadata. This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071064/811830

Answer (score 3):

#### New since iOS 8

It was complicated with **[ALAssetLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/)**, which is now deprecated, use **[Photos.Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/)** instead.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let assertURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([assertURL], options: nil)
        if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset
        {
            print(asset.location)
        }
    }
}
```

Quick and easy :)

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is nil in this case. cuze it's not saved yet. no URL exists.

Comment: Do you mean `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]` is `nil` for you? @XuYin

Answer (score 1):

It's a 'bug', I guess. A `UIImagePickerViewController` won't return location data of the images you select from it: as you've discovered, they are stripped from the meta data.

However, if you use `ALAssetLibrary` to get your images you **can** get the location data (in the form of a `CLLocation` object associated with the image). There is some code in this question - [iphone image ALAsset problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063244/iphone-image-alasset-problem) - that will help you get an `ALAsset` from a `UIImagePickerController`.

Of course, this would be easier if you could just get that information from the picker straight away, so consider filing a feature request with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm just trying to implement the code you linked but whenever I try and get the image reference url using `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]` it just returns NULL. I assume it's because the picture taken isn't saved to the phone (if I select an existing photo, it finds the URL fine). If I use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save the image, can I get the reference URL from that?

Answer (score 1):

As your source type would appear to be `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, this gets very frustrating very quickly, as you already know. Location info appears to be MIA.

As an alternative to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` (which does not refer to the saved image) I've tried **ALAssetsLibrary** and `-writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` (using `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` to populate it, hoping the framework would fill in the blanks with location info).

Alas, no such luck. Even though this method gives back a URL to the saved image, I still can't get `ALAssetPropertyLocation` info from it. Even if I use the orientation variant of the save method, it is of no use.

At this point, I think the only recourse would appear to be [incorporating your own location info, as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884060/saving-geotag-info-with-photo-on-ios4-1).

It seems somewhat fishy that I'd have to do this, however, as *I would expect the framework to handle this for you automagically*. In fact, I can't even get location info for *previously* taken photos. This is with all permissions granted in all the right places, no matter which device I use, iPhone or iPad. (Even the Camera app has proper permission, FWIW.)