# How to fetch latitude,longitude or address from photo which is taken from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to fetch latitude,longitude or address from photo which is taken from camera ,I have used the link [iPhone Get UIImagePickerController Lat/Lng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177606/iphone-get-uiimagepickercontroller-lat-lng/6454102#6454102)

and the code which I used is,

So this is how we handle the info given by the picker:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
            didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoCamera) {
        // We'll store the info to use in another function later
        self.imageInfo = info;

        // Get the asset url
        NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

        // We need to use blocks. This block will handle the ALAsset that's returned: 
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            // Get the location property from the asset  
            CLLocation *location = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            // I found that the easiest way is to send the location to another method
            [self handleImageLocation:location];
        };
        // This block will handle errors:
        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
            // Do something to handle the error
        };


        // Use the url to get the asset from ALAssetsLibrary,
        // the blocks that we just created will handle results
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:url 
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];

    }
}
```

But the location variable returns nil. How extract the location or address from photo which is taken from camera.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6454102/3157208 check this

Comment: @Ani Prasad. Actually i followed that link only .if you observe there is same code

Comment: Is the photo localized? If you go to Photos.app and choose it, is it localized? For example, screenshots or photo got from (FaceBook, WhatsApp, etc.) may not be localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this below code for location from camera picture..Hope this helps you

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {

    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoCamera) {
    // We'll store the info to use in another function later
    self.imageInfo = info;

    // Get the asset url
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    // We need to use blocks. This block will handle the ALAsset that's returned: 
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        // Get the location property from the asset  

        CLLocation *location = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
        // I found that the easiest way is to send the location to another method

        self.lat =location.coordinate.latitude; //[[gpsdata valueForKey:@"Latitude"]floatValue];
        self.lng =location.coordinate.longitude;
        NSLog(@"\nLatitude: %f\nLongitude: %f",self.lat,self.lng);

        strLocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"La:%f Lo%f",self.lat,self.lng];

        NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",strLocation);

    };
    // This block will handle errors:
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Can not get asset - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);

    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url 
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:failureblock];

}
 }
```

Comment: where i have to use this method in my code? please clarify me

Comment: In place of ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock block

Comment: i am getting asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata data nil

Comment: can you give a simple and sweet code sample example?

Comment: i have just took a glance on it.in  that metadata there is no {GPS} key or latitude and longitude. after applying your code will i get it?

Comment: Can you check the updated with code with valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation.. ..As  defaultRepresentation  is going to be deprecated method soon iOS 9 :https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAsset/defaultRepresentation

Comment: Are you able to get the location details now?

Comment: my xcode is 6.3 .xcode 6.4 or 7 will i get ios 9 sdk?

Comment: ok sowmya thanks for your relpy. very soon days i will update my code.your older project is able to get latitude and longitude?